# Check which files are currently syncing to iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud

Is it possible to see which files are *currently* syncing to iCloud Drive (in the same way you can with OneDrive, Dropbox and others)? I keep seeing this sort of thing in my Finder status bar:

[image: 2 items, 82.16 GB available on iCloud, uploading 1 item (226.8 MB of 226.8 MB)]

However, I've not changed any files recently, and certainly not a large 226.8 MB file. How can I determine what is currently being synced?

To be clear, I'm hoping to see something like this (this is what OneDrive shows):
[image: OneDrive upload]

This tells me that it is currently doing a 407.2 MB upload, but also specifically that it is the file `test.mp4` which is being uploaded. Seeing this would be really handy to understand why it was doing something (e.g. “oh, I did change that file” vs “that file definitely hasn't been changed, why is iCloud uploading it again?”).

Answer (score -2):

System Preferences > iCloud you can see which files are synchronized in your iCloud. Or, in your Finder, you have your favorites (Download, Desktop..) and underneath iCloud, inside you can see your files that are synced. Maybe that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think you answer how to check what files _should_ be downloaded locally – I'm asking a slightly different question. I've added some clarification to the original question.